# Using regex expressions within VBA's Find and Replace tool

Tags: regex, vba, replace, find

Is there a way to use regex expressions within the VBA editor's find and replace tool?

[image: Screenshot of Find and Replace Tool]

for example:
I've turned pattern matching on but my regex expressions do not seem to work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a way to use regex expressions within the VBA editor's find and replace tool?

- Nope.

**But**, if you want to replace something per `Sub`, you can loop all Subs, check for `Private` and add something like this:

```
For Each objComp In objPro.VBComponents
    If objComp.Type = 1 Then
        strText = objComp.CodeModule.Lines(1, UP_TO_LINE)

        If InStr(1, strText, PRIVATE_MODULE) = 0 Then
            objComp.CodeModule.InsertLines 2, PRIVATE_MODULE
        End If

    End If
Next objComp
```

The whole code is from this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41612479/5448626

---

Playing with the VBEditor & VBA is quite interesting:

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win002.htm

Comment: I believe the find and replace wildcards operate the same as with using the `Like` operator in VBA. For anything complex VBA is your best bet.