# Adding code to new worksheets dynamically from a excel vba module

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to dynamically add code to a worksheet from excel vba module. Like adding `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)` event code to a particular worksheet dynamically whenever I create a new worksheet.

Comment: This is possible (I think...), but I wouldn't recommend it. Instead consider using, in the ThisWorkbook code page: `Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)` `sh` will hold the sheet that called the event and `target` as usual is the selection made by the user in the `sh` sheet.

Comment: See the answers here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41612140/automatically-add-option-private-module-to-all-modules-in-vba

Comment: If the `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange` event suggested by @JNevill doesn't work for you consider creating very hidden template sheets containing the code.  Then you just need to copy the template sheet rather than add a new sheet and insert the code.

Comment: This is possible, see @Vityata his remark. However, it is advisable not to take this approach. You will have to alter security options in the VBE and you're basically catering for malicious code injection and execution.
I don't know what the goal is, but it is probably better to Event Sink the Application or the newly added Workbook/Worksheet or something similar.